# What is a good URI design for creating a new resource?

Tags: reactjs, web, react-router, uri

I currently have:

`/exercises`, which lists all exercises

And `/exercises/1`, which shows exercise with `id 1`

One exercise can have zero or many runs:

`/runs`    Shows all runs across all exercises

`/runs/1`  Shows run with is 1

So how can I have a page that allows you to create a run for an exercise?

Options I thought of are:

- 1. `/exercises/1/run-wizard`
- 2. `/runs/wizard?exerciseId=1`

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you. One way to go would be:

```
/exercises/:id1/run/add     <-- ADD RUN TO EXERCISE id1
/exercises/:id1/run/:id2    <-- ACCESS RUN id2 ON EXERCISE id1
```